# cannot change imageview src after closing camera intent

Tags: android, android-imageview

I'm have a small problem.

objective of code: click an imageview that opens the camera, then after getting a picture change the imageview.  the imageview is not a thumbnail of the photo.

the problem:  the imageview does not refresh.

what I've tried: [Android imageView Switching Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888078/android-imageview-switching-problem?rq=1),
[Changing ImageView on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490953/changing-imageview-on-button-click),
[ImageView onClickListener changing the image source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497157/imageview-onclicklistener-changing-the-image-source?rq=1)
(Can’t use viewSwitcher b/c have more than two possible view combinations),
[how to change the background or the image source when a clickable imageview in android is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544904/how-to-change-the-background-or-the-image-source-when-a-clickable-imageview-in-a?rq=1)

My code:

```
public class CacTestActivity extends Activity {

private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 2500;
private Bitmap bmp;
private ImageView ivPic;
private Thread thread;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cactest);

    ivPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgCacSetPhoto);

    ivPic.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    });
    thread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            ivPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgCacSetPhoto);
            ivPic.setImageResource(R.drawable.takephotoyes);
            ivPic.invalidate();
        }
    };
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST){
            //If getting pic bitmap is successful, then change imageview source
            //thread.start();       //Does not work
        }
    }
}
}
```

This question has been asked many times before, but after much searching I've yet to find a solution.  What am I missing?  thanks

Comment: Why are you calling `setImageResource` on another thread?  operations that change the UI such as this one should be run on the UI thread so there is no need to run it in another thread.

Comment: @James: using a thread was a suggestion on SO.  After wasting hours, I've found the SOLUTION - it simply does not work on the emulator.  Changing the imageview src in the onActivityResult works on my actual phone. [In case anyone is wondering, I used ivPic.setImageResource() and not the thread in my code] This concerns me a little.  How do I test thoroughly, then? The emulator targets API level 10.  Is this a known issue?

Comment: what is your target API in your manifest? what is your target android sdk in your project properties in eclipse?

Comment: How did you ever make that deduction? Brilliant! That's the problem. When I changed the project build target to match (it was lower) the manifest target api level, the image src changed in the emulator.  Thank you @James.  I read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938348/difference-between-build-target-sdk-in-eclipse-and-androidtargetsdkversion-in) but are there any other good sources for project build target vs. targetSdkVersion?

Comment: I would like to give James credit for the solution or mark my question as answered, but I don't see how that is done.

Comment: I put my comment up as an answer if you want to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your target Android version in project properties in Eclipse and your targetSdk in your manifest match.

- Right click project > Properties > Android tab, and make sure the selected Android target matches your targetSdk